# Gzip not working on local development

Tags: php, linux, compression, gzip, mamp

I am using a Kohana minifier module to compress less/ css and js files into type combined files.

`/less/f31e419e939bfec51b4fe8322f545455.less?r=20130618`
`/js/24dae189814109f20ff9a5bf4422be36.js?r=20130618`

I am using MAMP PRO but receive the following error on Firefox and Chrome:

```
Content Encoding Error
This webpage is not available
```

The content headers are coming through as:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 18 Jun 2013 11:17:14 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.4
Etag: "acf11d952c07adb223fa77f3d385f56e"
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
Last-Modified: Thu, 13 Jun 2013 21:57:04 +0000
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 16894
Set-Cookie: session_database=ecfc139402165669a4b6d5e8190564231133fb0d%7E51c041ba9f6e95-28008580; expires=Wed, 19-Jun-2013 11:17:17 GMT; path=/
Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8
```

The content works if I remove the gzip encoding but obviously I would like to take advantage of the gzip compression. My PHP code is:

```
// Further up the page
$data['cache_gz'] = gzencode($data['cache']);

//...

if ($gzip === FALSE){
    $this->response->body($data['cache']); // Works
}else{
    this->response->headers('Content-Encoding', $gzip); // Doesn't Work

    $this->response->headers('Content-Length', strlen($data['cache_gz']));
    $this->response->body($data['cache_gz']);
}
```

Would really appreciate some guidance with this as I am stumped as to how to solve this issue or if it is just related to being on a local server.

Comment: Did enable mod_deflate on your local apache?

Comment: Yes all of the modules are load including mod_deflate

Comment: on php.net manpage of gzencode function. One comment suggests to add ini_set('zlib.output_compression','Off'); before gzencode. And why you use gzencode(...) even if gzip flag is False ?

Comment: Ensure all error messages are turned off, with white spaces eliminated from file endings and beginnings, also ensure that mod_deflate is not re-encoding the already encoded data.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://php.net/manual/ru/function.gzcompress.php
It may help you, like it helped me one time :))

Answer (score 0):

This may just be a typo in your post, but

```
this->response->headers('Content-Encoding', $gzip);
```

should be

```
$this->response->headers('Content-Encoding', $gzip);
```